# Software PWM on a PIC10F202 (looped fading LED)

Tags: led, pic, c, pwm

I'm currently trying my best to code a software solution for PWM on a PIC20F202 but I have one issue. I'm trying a looped fade out and fade with a LED and it's doing fine and very smoothly but on somewhat regular intervals, there is a hard bump in the fading sequence which I can't explain by any means. I have looked at the code so many times, I checked the contacts on the breadboard, I don't know what else to check for.

```
/******************************************************************************/
/* Files to Include                                                           */
/******************************************************************************/

#if defined(__XC)
    #include <xc.h>         /* XC8 General Include File */
#elif defined(HI_TECH_C)
    #include <htc.h>        /* HiTech General Include File */
#endif

#include <stdint.h>        /* For uint8_t definition */
#include <stdbool.h>       /* For true/false definition */

#include "system.h"        /* System funct/params, like osc/peripheral config */
#include "user.h"          /* User funct/params, such as InitApp */

/******************************************************************************/
/* User Global Variable Declaration                                           */
/******************************************************************************/

/* i.e. uint8_t <variable_name>; */

/******************************************************************************/
/* Main Program                                                               */
/******************************************************************************/

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

void main(void)
{
    /* Configure the oscillator for the device */
    ConfigureOscillator();

    /* Initialize I/O and Peripherals for application */
    InitApp();

    /* TODO <INSERT USER APPLICATION CODE HERE> */
    const uint8_t MAX = 100;
    uint16_t oncount=1;
    int8_t delta=1;

    TRIS = 0b111101;

        for(;;){

                GPIO = 0b000010;
                for(uint16_t i=1;i<oncount;i++)
                    __delay_us(1);

                GPIO =0;
                for(uint16_t i=1;i<(MAX-oncount);i++)
                    __delay_us(1);

                oncount += delta;

                if(oncount == MAX)
                    delta = delta * (-1);
                if(oncount == 0)
                    delta = delta * (-1);

        }



}
```

Comment: Does the hard bump come in regular intervals? Does the hard bump mean that the sequence starts from the beginning?

Comment: Try clearing the watchdog timer (clrwdt) inside the main loop.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a mess around with your code, simplifying it a bit to get a simple fade in working. I had to change a few things as I used a PIC16F690, but here's the main routine (had to write simple delay routine as some of the header files were not found)
Not had any sleep here, so my brains a bit fuddled (i.e. I haven't looked at why your code is't working - maybe the WDT as I just noted from the comments - notice the `#pragma WDTE = OFF` in my code), but might help to get you started anyway.

```
#pragma config WDTE = OFF
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

void delay(int d);

void main(void)
{
    /* Configure the oscillator for the device */
   // ConfigureOscillator();

    /* Initialize I/O and Peripherals for application */
//    InitApp();

    /* TODO <INSERT USER APPLICATION CODE HERE> */
    const uint8_t MAX = 1000;
    uint16_t oncount=1;
    int8_t delta=1;

    TRISBbits.TRISB6 = 0;

        for(;;){

                PORTBbits.RB6 = 1;
                //for(uint16_t i=1;i<oncount;i++)
                    delay(oncount);

                PORTBbits.RB6 = 0;
                //for(uint16_t i=1;i<(MAX-oncount);i++)
                    delay(MAX - oncount);

                oncount++;

                if(oncount == MAX)
                  oncount = 0;
               // if(oncount == 0)
                 //   delta = delta * (-1);

        }



}

void delay(int d)
{
    while(d)
    {
        d--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted your configuration bits, but it may be that you have the watchdog timer enabled, and since you are not clearing it in the main loop, it may be timing out and resetting the microcontroller.  All your variables would be re-initialized and you would see the led jump back to off and ramping up.  This would happen over and over with a constant period.

Try clearing the watchdog timer in your main loop.